# Subsetting one list based on another list and then finding position of the maxima

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements, max

**UPDATED:**
I have two lists that look like this:

```
MyList1<-list(c(0,1,1,1),c(1,1,2,0))
MyList2<-list(c(4,5,6,2),c(5,5,2,5))
```

What I want to find are the positions in MyList2 of the maxima but only where the corresponding positions in MyList1 are >0. The result would be:

```
Result<-list(c(3),c())
```

To explain further where this result comes from, if you first subset the second list where MyList1>0 then you would have:

```
list(c(5,6,2),c(5,5,2))
```

The maximum element across both lists is 6 which only exists in list 1:

```
list(c(6),c())
```

The position of this in MyList2 are:

```
list(c(3),c())
```

I'm not sure of the best way to get to this desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mapply`, you can do this:

```r
m <- max(unlist(MyList2)[unlist(MyList1) > 0])
mapply(function(x,y) which(x == m & y > 0), MyList2, MyList1)

# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# integer(0)
```

---

With `purrr::map2`:

```r
purrr::map2(MyList2, MyList1, function(x,y) which(x == m & y > 0))

#or 

purrr::map2(MyList2, MyList1, ~ which(.x == m & .y > 0))
```

**data**

```r
MyList1<-list(c(0,1,1,1),c(1,1,2,0))
MyList2<-list(c(4,5,6,2),c(5,5,2,5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I could have done better with my working of the question. The answer you gave answers it correctly for separate maximas in each list, however, I was looking for the positions of a global maxima across both lists. I have edited the question with an update at the bottom. You will see entering those lists in the second example doesn't get to the desired result.

Comment: See my edited answer. It should work fine.